# Flutter and Firebase Add Objects to List

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first question.
Right now my code is working when adding 'displayName' to List:

```
final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
List userList = [];
void getUsers() async {
  List<String> newUserList = [];
  await usersRef.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
      newUserList.add(data['displayName']);
    });
  });
  setState(() {
    userList = newUserList;
  });
}
```

But I want to add 'userList[id]' AND 'userList[displayName]' to list the 'displayName' in DropDown BUT to send(push) the 'id':

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
  ...
  items: userList,
  ...
  onChanged: (String value) {
    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage(profileId: value),
  ...
```

Because in DropDown-List Names could be duplicate like John Doe but a List of unique IDs to select makes no sense ... Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The `await` in `await usersRef.get()...` is not doing anything, since you're not returning anything from within the callback.

I highly recommend using *either* `async`/`await` *or* `then`, but not both.

With `then` the code would be:

```
void getUsers() {
  List<String> newUserList = [];
  usersRef.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
      newUserList.add(data['displayName']);
    });
    setState(() {
      userList = newUserList;
    });
  });
}
```

And with `async`/`await` it'd be:

```
void getUsers() async {
  List<String> newUserList = [];
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await usersRef.get();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
    newUserList.add(data['displayName']);
  });
  setState(() {
    userList = newUserList;
  });
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU Frank for the corrections and the improvement of code. Do you have any idea how to use the Users-displayName for selection and using Users-ID to refer the selection?

Comment: Hey @TobiasM. Did you try the code from my answer yet? Did that make any difference to the results you're getting?

Comment: Hey Frank, it seems the results are the same. But I am still have the same problem: as search items I have to list NAMES so that users can identify the person they search. But I need ID to store in database to later call ID-dependent functions. My solution now is to create two lists. newUserListNames and newUserListIDs. When selecting an item in newUserListNames ["Peter","Paul","Mary"] I use indexOf() ["Mary"=2] to identify position of that name in Names-List and with that position I get ID from related ID in ID-List ["1234","5678","9012"] => "Mary" = 2 = "9012". What do you think?

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. 